# Have libraries navigation using arrows in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint

I am currently working on the homepage on a Sharepoint online site.
Is there a way to allow the user to navigate between some libraries using arrows? Kind of the same as Image Gallery web part but instead of having images, have directly the different library displayed.

Thank you in advance for the help !

Answer (score 0):

We can not use SharePoint modern document web part, so we could use [DetailedList](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/detailslist) instead.
Official example renderings：
[image]
We can write a button on the left and right of the DetailedList to switch the data source of the DetailedList.

Then you can achieve the effect similar to the carousel.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !
I think I see what you mean but I'm really not an expert on that. How would I make the button and code to switch the data source?

Comment: We need to initiate a request to SharePoint to obtain library items and files and assign them to the DetailedList component. Set the button click event to change the requested URL, and then the library displayed in the DetailedList can be changed.